# neo4j does not start with Neo4j.bat

Tags: windows, neo4j

When I double click (on windows 8) in Neo4j.bat it show me for a second the command prompt, showing me the error "impossibile trovare il percorso specificato" the command prompt closes.

Searching on google the error is not found. The version is 1.9.2 but also the previous 1.9 and 2.0.0-M03 gives me same problem.

Answer (score 1):

The error translates to "cannot find the path specified." With that, you'll find a few posts, such as [this one](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/neo4j/135st1a5m4/issues-with-installing-neo4j-1-9-with-java-1-7-on-windows-7), discussing the problem. The answer involves a few things:

- Removing `\bin` from `JAVA_HOME` and `JRE_HOME`
- Making sure the `bin` path is in your path
- changing base.bat to `windows-service-wrapper-4.jar` instead of `windows-service-wrapper-*.jar`

This is all outlined in the Windows 7 installation video found [here](http://www.neo4j.org/download/windows).